# Install extension to all Firefox profiles in my Ubuntu user account?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

There are 2 Ubuntu user accounts.

I have about 6-7 Firefox profiles in **my** Ubuntu user account.

I want to install an extension into all of them **but not** into Firefox profiles of the other Ubuntu user account.

How do I?

Answer (score -1):

Start Firefox with every profile and install the extension...

```
firefox -P
```

or

```
firefox -ProfileManager
```

Comment: The `-P` option opens the profile manager from which you can choose a profile. How will that install the addon in all profiles?

Comment: Please read my comment: _Start Firefox with every profile and install the extension_

Comment: Okay, that is quite obvious. I am looking for a place where I could leave the extension so Firefox could pick it up to all the required profiles.

Comment: Not very helpful answer!